# Convex analysis of $h(x) = \log (f(x)) \ $ for $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R, \mathbb{R}_+})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

> **Problem**: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be of Class $C^2$ such that $$g(x)= f(x)e^{cx} \text{ is convex } \forall c \in \mathbb{R} $$
>   Verify that $h(x)= \log(f(x))$ is convex

**My approach**: Since $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_+)$ it seems to me to be the most reasonable approach to show that the 2nd derivative of $h$ is greater than or equal to 0.

First I said that $$g(x)=f(x)e^{cx} \iff f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{e^{cx}} $$because $e^{cx} >0$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$, plugging this expression into the definition of $h$  to obtain $$h(x)= \log\left( \frac{g(x)}{e^{cx}}\right) $$
Clearly $h$ is of Class $C^2$ because it is a composition of $C^2$ functions so I took both derivatives, I did it twice on paper and checked my results with the help of Mathematica, so you can assume the results to be right. I obtain: $$h'(x)= \frac{g'(x)-cg(x)}{g(x)}  $$
For the first derivative and $$h''(x)= \frac{g''(x)}{g(x)}- \left( \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right)^2 \tag{*} $$ for the second derivative, for which I find it not possible to draw a conclusion about it being $\geq 0$

Additionally to that I also tried to compute the derivatives of $g$ and substitute them back into (*) but then, thanks to the layout of the problem, I only obtain $$h''(x)= \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}- \left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2 $$
Is there a theorem I am missing ? Or is my approach wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ is convex for every $c$, $g'' \ge 0$ for all $c$, which implies

$$f''(x) + 2cf'(x) + c^2 f(x) \ge 0\quad \text{for all} \quad c, x\in \Bbb R.$$

Given $x\in \Bbb R$, set $c = -f'(x)/f(x)$ to get

$$f''(x) -  \frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)} \ge 0,$$

or

$$f(x)f''(x) - f'(x)^2 \ge 0.$$

Since the inequality holds for all $x\in \Bbb R$,

$$h''(x) = \frac{f(x)f''(x) - f'(x)^2}{f(x)^2} \ge 0$$

for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Therefore, $h$ is convex.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a hint. Your approach is ignoring the statement that the convexity of $f(x) e^{cx}$ is given for *every* $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Actually in your approach $c$ cancels out.

Start by writing down what that means for the second derivative of that function. You'll arrive at an inequality for $f^{\prime\prime}$ in terms of $cf^\prime$ and $c^2 f$, valid for any $c$ (!).

Now write down the second derivative of $\log f$ and try to show that this is nonnegative.

Comment: I have had this all on paper already (just didn't work with it). I end up with the statement that $c^2f(x) + 2cf'(x)+f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. So I assume that I now need to pick my $c$ clever in order to show that the 2nd derivative of $h$ is positive (I have already written that expression in the OP). I can say that $f''(x) \geq 0$ by picking $c=0$ besides that I can only see that $$2c\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \geq \frac{-c^2f(x)-f''(x)}{f(x)}=-c^2- \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} $$

Comment: @Spaced as I have said in my answer, given $x\in \Bbb R$, set $c = -f'(x)/f(x)$ in the inequality to get $f''(x)f(x) - f'(x)^2 \ge 0$. Dividing by $f(x)^2$ results in $h''(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: @Kobe thanks, I have read your answer just now, I was working on figuring out that approach on my own and just saw your post after I refreshed that page :) I accepted your answer